# checking ASP.net webAPI out using TFS with GIT into different directory causes missing directive or assembly reference errors

Tags: c#, .net, git, asp.net-web-api, tfs

I had a ASP.net 4.5 webAPI that worked well that was located in C:\users\me\source\MyProject .

I then needed to push this project to a new Git Repo in Visual studio online.

to push it there I did the following

```
git remote add origin https://my-cool-webAPI.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/MYcoolProject 
git push -u origin --all
```

Everything appeared to be fine.

So i then cloned this project from the Visual Studio Online TFS Git repo to a new source directory.

It was in `C:/users/me/source/MyProject` and I moved it to `C:\Users\me\Desktop\Source\MyProject`

Now I have 166 errors and 166 warnings complaining about assembly references.

[image]

Here is more detail on a specific error.

[image]

**Any idea what I did wrong?**

** it looks like my references are out of wack, Notice it doesnt know the path to find Entity-Framework.
[image]

**Is this because I didnt check in the Packages folder or something else**

How do I refresh them? and How does one ensure they make it to source control, ie are they managed by a certain file similar to say a Rails Gemfile?

Currently I am doing the following steps to try and run my WebAPI that had no errors before I moved it to this new repo.

1. Clean the solution (that succeeds)
2. Build the solution (166 errors and 166 warnings)

Comment: Have you looked at your references? It may be pointing to the old absolute path, or simply the assemblies weren't uploaded to source control (which is in fact the right thing to do). Try removing the references and adding the nuget packages again.

Comment: sorry most of my experience on the front and or using a rails backend on a linux distor. How would I do that @bateloche ? thanks and in short no i havent

Comment: how do i ensure the references get check in?

Comment: do not check in the references. Instead, remove the references from the project and re add them using nuget

Comment: @bateloche so delete everything in the packages folder or should I remove the references a different way

Comment: remove the references directly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82546/discussion-between-bateloche-and-bob-sinclar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bateloche was on the money with his comments

In order to fix this I had to do the following.

1. I had to delete my packages folder.
2. Make sure your packages folder wasnt checked in by default its in the gitignore file that visual studio by defuault generates so it shouldnt be check in.

   3. in VS goto Tools ->  NuGet Package Manager -> settings  and enabable Nuget to download missing packages.
   4. Make sure to open the package manager console and click accept to refresh the nuget packages. **The gotcha was that you may have to restart visual studio for this to work**